# code does only run correctly in break mode

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

After hours and days of searching the web in order to find a hint how to fix a bug in my code, I am completely clueless about what might be going on, and am hoping to get some advise from this community.

The code is somewhat complicated, therefore I will not add any snippets, but rather try to explain as simple as I can get it.

- I have created a tool (excel macro) that does a lot of analyses on certain data, collected at customer sites using our software (mostly multiple users)
- This tool runs well since years, including e.g. filtering to only take into account users that match certain criteria
- I want to expand that tool in a way so that it automatically runs multiple times - once for each user.

The way how this works is:
The tool processes data from the first user, and saves the result as a new excel spreadsheet (in which the code continues to run).
the tool processes data from the next user, and again saves the result as a new spreadsheet, and so on.

In the second run the weird behaviour happens: If run in regular mode, the code breaks due to an error; if the code is interrupted by a 'stop' right before the line producing the error and code completion is continued, everything works perfectly fine.

The problem occurs at assignment of a table as range:

```
Dim rr As Range
Set rr = Workbooks(actWBK).Worksheets(shtName).Range(tableName & "[[#All],[" & header & "]]")
```

From the second run onwards, the line starting with Set... produces an error (application-defined or object-defined error).

The fact that this assignment works perfectly in the first run made me believe that there is some kind of unspecified assignment to a workbook or the like, but I tested all options and could rule that out;

The really staggering thing is that, as mentioned, when I add a "stop" before, the code works perfectly fine.

I am really out of any ideas, so every answer is more than welcome!

Thank you in advance,

Alexander

I will try to add some code. 
The problem occurs in the module sortTable (relevant part after "code here", I always use this kind of "template" to set some standard things):

```
Sub sortTable(sheetName As String, tableName As String, header As String, dir As XlSortOrder)

' here only logging and error handling settings
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' code here
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' deal with @-sign in header

Dim headerParts() As String
headerParts = Split(header, "@")

Dim cleanHeader As String

If UBound(headerParts) = -1 Then

    successcode = 2
    GoTo errorHandler

ElseIf UBound(headerParts) = 0 Then

    cleanHeader = header

Else

    cleanHeader = headerParts(0)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To UBound(headerParts)

        cleanHeader = cleanHeader & "'@" & headerParts(i)

    Next i

End If

' sorting


Dim actWBK As String
actWBK = ActiveWorkbook.name

Dim rr As Range
Set rr = Workbooks(actWBK).Worksheets(sheetName).Range(tableName & "[[#All],[" & cleanHeader & "]]")

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(tableName).Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(tableName).Sort.SortFields _
.Add key:=Range(tableName & "[[#All],[" & cleanHeader & "]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
:=dir, DataOption:=xlSortNormal


With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(tableName).Sort
    .header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = True
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With



'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' sub cleanup on exit; don't make changes below this line
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' here only logging and error handling

End Sub
```

The procedure is called from a different module called QuickSort which takes as argument an array:

```
Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant)

' here only logging and error handling


Dim wsName As String
wsName = "tempSort"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(wsName).Delete
On Error GoTo errorHandler
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
ActiveSheet.name = wsName

Cells(1, 1) = "Header"

Dim rr As Range

Set rr = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(UBound(vArray) + 2 - LBound(vArray), 1))
Set rr = rr.Resize(UBound(vArray) + 1 - LBound(vArray), 1)

rr.value = myTransposeArray(vArray)

Set rr = Nothing

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add( _
xlSrcRange, _
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(vArray) + 2 - LBound(vArray), 1)), _
, xlYes).name = "tempSortTable"

sortTable sheetName:=wsName, tableName:="tempSortTable", header:="Header", dir:=xlAscending

' more code hereafter
```

Comment: It may be a memory Problem. Are you sure that the data is saved before the line of code is reached? Not likely, yet my first thought.

Comment: A wild guess is based on "... as a new excel spreadsheet (in which the code continues to run)". If the *other* code starts running, but needs to reach a certain point - such as creating a worksheet - then the breakpoint is allowing this code to complete. I would consider why there needs to be separate code initiated, and possibly introducing a delay (OnTime) in the first code, although this isn't a perfect approach.

Comment: I would also split your statement into a few lines, to determine whether it is the book, sheet or range that is at issue.

Comment: @Andy G: Thank you for your suggestions. It was obviously misleading, but there is only "one code" running. What I do is to start the original tool, it loads data, and is then saved with a new name. At the next iteration, the previous data is deleted, re-imported, and again saved with a a new name. Regarding splitting to determine what is at issue: I am not sure anything of these (book ,sheet, range) is at issue, as it works after break.

Comment: @C. Henke: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately, saving is not of relevance at this point. Still thank you!

Comment: This isn't really a question for SO. There's nothing for us to reproduce and it's too much of a stab in the dark to come up with anything that will actually help you. We really do need some code so we can **reproduce your problem**. Tell me this: how is `actWBK` defined? something like `actWBK = ActiveWorkbook.Name`?

Comment: @CallumDA: OK, I understand your point. I will add some code with some clarifications.

Comment: Whenever I see people saying their code works in break mode but not normally/ vica versa I immediately think about whether they are using {`ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell`, `Select`}. Remove all instances and test your code again. Rather than `ActiveWorkbook`,use `ThisWorkbook` or declare other workbooks fully (by name).

Comment: Hi CallumDA, thank you for your suggestion, I did change to ThisWorkbook (although only one workbook is open anyway), unfortunately it did not change behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collegue of mine found a workaround to overcome the problem (all credits onto you, Thomas!):

instead of referencing the range as

```
Set rr = Workbooks(actWBK).Worksheets(sheetName).Range(tableName & "[[#All],[" & cleanHeader & "]]")
```

I changed the code to

```
Set rr = Workbooks(actWBK).Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(tableName).ListColumns(cleanHeader).Range
```

By that, everything works perfectly fine, no matter if in the first run or in subsequent runs.

There is also a suspicion what might cause the problem (which clearly is not resolved itself, this solution is just a workaround!), and it has to do with something going on during saving the workbook using SaveAs.

I am not clear at all what could be this reason, but for those who face a similar problem, I'd like to explain what I did in my code:

By opening a file containing the tool

AnalysisTool.xlsm

the macro starts running. In order to get data, the code opens an xml file as excel table; this table temporarily is called something like

Book1.xlsx

The code copies the data from Book1 to AnalysisTool; in order to remain the tool unchanged, the file is saved as something like

AnalysisResult_20180222_01.xlsm  <- this is the file in which code is executed!

Book1 is closed without saving.

When the analysis is finished, the workbook is saved without close.

Upon re-run,

All result tabs in AnalysisResult_20180222_01.xlsm are deleted, a new xml data file is opened, data is copied, and the code-bearing file is saved as

AnalysisResult_20180222_02.xlsm <- this is the file in which code now is executed!

etc.

As I said, I am not sure what goes wrong, but by changing this one line as described makes everything work perfectly fine.

Hope this might be helpful to anybody!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
Dim actWBK As String
actWBK = ActiveWorkbook.name

Dim rr As Range
Set rr = Workbooks(actWBK).Worksheets(sheetName).Range(tableName & "[[#All],[" & cleanHeader & "]]")
```

To

```
Dim actWbk as workbook
Set actwbk = activeworkbook
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = actwbk.worksheets(sheetname)
dim s as string
s = tableName & "[[#All],[" & cleanHeader & "]]"
Dim rr as range
Set rr = ws.range(s)
```

Then when it breaks you can inspect each in turn to see if they point to what you think they should

Comment: Thank you for the proposal! I did change according to your suggestion, the code again fails and goes to errorHandler in which I placed 'stop' followed by 'resume' (I am aware this must not be the case in production code). Again the strange thing is: Resume puts the active line back to "Set rr = ws.Range(s)"; if I now continue by pressing F5, the code runs without a problem. The error btw is again 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: It seems even more weird to me, that, given the fact that I call this subroutine a couple of times, if it leads to an error the first time (in the second run of the tool), it always leads to an error subsequently; if by Stop->Resume it does not create an error anymore, then it does neither in any of the subsequent calls...

Comment: on stop what is the value of s?